# Javascript Regular Expression to Replace All Phone Numbers in HTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all phone numbers (Singapore Number) in my HTML to clickable links `<a href="tel:xxxx"></a>` based on below rules :-

```
3xxx xxxx - Voice Over IP services
6xxx xxxx - Fixed Line services inclusive of Fixed Line Voice Over IP services
                       (e.g. StarHub Digital Voice and SingTel mio Voice)
7zxx xxxx - Mobile phone services (Starting 2015)
8zxx xxxx - Mobile phone services
9yxx xxxx - Mobile phone services (pager services until May 2012)

x denotes 0 to 9
y denotes 0 to 8 only.
z denotes 1 to 9 only.
```

So I created this regular expression :-

```
(\+?65)?\s?(((3|6)[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{4})|((7|8)[1-9][0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{4})|((9)[0-8][0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{4}))\b
```

After that, I tested the regular expression using below strings :-

```
98749326
6436 6618
+65 6220 0878
00D90000000ypka
http://domain.com/resources/98749326-efa0-11e3-8c7f-22000aa41488
```

And the matched results as below :-

```
98749326
6436 6618
+65 6220 0878
http://domain.com/resources/98749326-efa0-11e3-8c7f-22000aa41488
```

The problem is, how to omitted the last string? `http://domain.com/resources/98749326-efa0-11e3-8c7f-22000aa41488`

The last string is random media url. So all media url will be replaced too if I'm using the regular expression.

I tried to use `^(\+?65)?\s?(((3|6)[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{4})|((7|8)[1-9][0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{4})|((9)[0-8][0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{4}))$` its working and omitted the url but, when I use in the javascript, its not replacing all phone numbers.

Below is my javascript :-

```
var SGphoneNumberConverter;

SGphoneNumberConverter = function(html) {
  var sgPhoneRegex;
  sgPhoneRegex = new RegExp("^(\\+?65)?\\s?(((3|6)[0-9]{3}\\s?[0-9]{4})|((7|8)[1-9][0-9]{2}\\s?[0-9]{4})|((9)[0-8][0-9]{2}\\s?[0-9]{4}))$", "gi");
  return html.replace(sgPhoneRegex, "<a href=\"tel:$1 $2\">$1 $2</a>");
};

if (!/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  $("body").html(SGphoneNumberConverter($("body").html()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to enable multiline modifier. Using anchored regex against an input which has only single line won't create any problems. But if the input contain multiple lines, then you must need to enable multiline modifier `m`

```
var sgPhoneRegex = new RegExp("^(\\+?65)?\\s?(((3|6)[0-9]{3}\\s?[0-9]{4})|((7|8)[1-9][0-9]{2}\\s?[0-9]{4})|((9)[0-8][0-9]{2}\\s?[0-9]{4}))$", "gmi");
```

**Example:**

```
> var s = '98749326\n6436 6618\n+65 6220 0878\n00D90000000ypka\nhttp://domain.com/resources/98749326-efa0-11e3-8c7f-22000aa41488';
undefined
> var sgPhoneRegex = new RegExp("^(\\+?65)?\\s?(((3|6)[0-9]{3}\\s?[0-9]{4})|((7|8)[1-9][0-9]{2}\\s?[0-9]{4})|((9)[0-8][0-9]{2}\\s?[0-9]{4}))$", "gmi");
undefined
> console.log(s.replace(sgPhoneRegex, '<a href="tel:$1 $2">$1 $2</a>'))
<a href="tel: 98749326"> 98749326</a>
<a href="tel: 6436 6618"> 6436 6618</a>
<a href="tel:+65 6220 0878">+65 6220 0878</a>
00D90000000ypka
http://domain.com/resources/98749326-efa0-11e3-8c7f-22000aa41488
```

Comment: You just rant too much about down votes :D and you shouldn't care about them. I think there are many people which admire you! (Including me)

Comment: @Rizier123 you the one of some people who encourages me all the time. Feel free to ask me if you have any doubts in my answers.  :)

Comment: *if you have any doubts* no, just reading, being impressed and learning. (Sometimes i have the feeling you just learnt the regex part of every program language :D) Keep up the interesting answers! And questions (http://stackoverflow.com/q/28390779/3933332) I think people like you should get more compliments for the great work and sharing the knowledge

Comment: @Rizier123 did you know the answer for that question? If the arrays in php won't allow duplicate names then what's the use of `J` modifier. I really don't understand [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390779/how-to-use-j-modifier-in-php#comment45119347_28390881) comment.

Comment: I don't understand it fully, also my knowledge about regex isn't very good. Why not just ask him what he means? Or for some more examples where you can use the modifier