# PHP What sub-pattern will be used when using "J" modifier which allows duplicate named sub patterns?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

in PCRE, the "J" modifier allows duplicate named sub patterns inside a regexp pattern.

> J
>
> (PCRE_INFO_JCHANGED) The (?J) internal option setting changes the
>   local PCRE_DUPNAMES option. Allow duplicate names for subpatterns.

But nothing is said about which pattern will be used when a recursive named sub-pattern is used in a regexp with duplicate named sub patterns.

For instance:
https://regex101.com/r/wY3wQ7/6

It seems that when there's the named recursion, the match is made against the first named sub-pattern only `(?P<NAME>pattern1)` and the second one `(?P<NAME>pattern2)` is ignored. Is it right? Then why could such a feature be useful?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use J modifier in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390779/how-to-use-j-modifier-in-php)

Comment: It's useful for cases where you don't care which one matches. So should be avoided if could possibly match two different sections, precisely because it's undefined which match is retained. (The PHP binding seems to prefer overwriting named captures, btw). Please explain what your concern is about recursive subpatterns in particular, the r101 example is just a list.

Comment: @mario, as you can see in the example, the last match which recurses to the previous named sub-pattern matches the first declared named sub pattern, I don't understand what you mean with 'what is your concern about recursive sub-patterns'. Anyway, I have found an example here, thanks to `Rizier123` http://3v4l.org/fnm76#v446, though it doesn't use recursive subpatterns.