# Match first occurence of a word and ignoring duplicates in a named group

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a PHP router engine for practice and i'm currently doing the regular expressions for it.

A mapped URL can have parameter patterns and are written down like `{type:varName}`. I don't want to allow that there are multiplle occurences of the variable name, which is `varName` in this case.

I've currently got this regex for it:

```
{(?<key>[a-zA-Z]{1,4}):(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b)(?!.*\1\b)}
```

[(live version here)](https://regex101.com/r/3S7IqE/2)

The problem is that it does only check for duplicates on the `<key>` group and not for the `<name>` group. Also it finds the last one occured instead of the first one found.

How do I make this regular expression so that it only matches the first occurence of the `<name>` group and does not match the duplicates of this first match?

---

**Example**

When you have a pattern like this:

```
{s:varName}-{i:varName}-{s:varName}
```

Only the first `{s:varName}` should match, the other 2 shouldn't be matched.

When there is an pattern like this:

```
{i:varName1}-{d:varName1}-{i:varName2}-{i:varName3}-{m:varName3}
```

`{i:varName1}`, `{i:varName2}` and `{i:varName3}` should match.

---

**Update**

Thanks to @sln I ended up with this regular expression:

```
{(?<key>[a-zA-Z]{1,4}):(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]+\b)}(?:(?!.*{[a-zA-Z_]{1,4}:\2))
```

The only problem with this is that it doesn't match the first occurunce but the latest one found.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't do a global search, just do a search. This will find the first only. What do you mean by duplicate in the name group ?  `{(?<key>[a-zA-Z]{1,4}):(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b)}(?!.*{\1:\2})`

Comment: What I mean by a duplicate in the name group is that you can have multiple `i`'s for the `<key>` group but not multiple occurences of `varName` for the `<name`> group. What do you mean by a global search?

Comment: I'm confused, for example, it's not possible to have a pattern like this: `{s:varName}-{i:varName}-{s:varName}` but something like this is allowed: `{i:varName1}-{i:varName2}-{i:varName3}`

Comment: I just gave you the regex `{(?<key>[a-zA-Z]{1,4}):(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b)}(?!.*{\1:\2})`

Comment: @sln That would still match duplicates of the `<name>` group: https://regex101.com/r/H4cuDJ/1

Comment: If you want to disqualify the line if any duplicate exist's, you'd have to match a line with a duplicate as a disqualification. I mean, otherwise, if you just want to verify the first one matched is not duplicated, use `^(?:(?!{[a-zA-Z]{1,4}:[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b}).)*{(?<key>[a-zA-Z]{1,4}):(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b)}(?!.*{\1:\2})`

Comment: For example, if `{(?<key>[a-zA-Z]{1,4}):(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b)}(?=.*{\1:\2})` it is disqualified, otherwise, you just need `{(?<key>[a-zA-Z]{1,4}):(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b)}` You'd have to do it this way because, it's hard for a regex to get what you need at the same time it's validating _all_ the individual pieces.

Comment: This is getting so confusing....It still matches the latest found match right?

Comment: It's only confusing because you maybe don't know exactly what you need.

Comment: This gets both operations in a single step, but it's huge `^(?!.*{([a-zA-Z]{1,4}):([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\b}.*{\1:\2}).*?{(?<key>[a-zA-Z]{1,4}):(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b)}`

Comment: @sln I'm starting to understand the first solution you gave me. But doesnt this part `(?!.*{\1:\2})` dont allow duplicates of both of the captured groups when they are the same? Also, it still only matches the latest found.

Comment: The first solution matches the _first_ pair that is not a duplicate of both \1 _and_ \2. Isn't both what you're interested in, as opposed to either/or ?

Comment: You have an odd requirement, first you say if {A}-{B}-{A}, only {A} should match. Then you say if {A}-{B}-{C} then all should match ? If you're looking to grab distinct key/var pairs, maybe match all of them and maintain a hash of the matches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136385/discussion-between-bas-and-sln).

Comment: @sln I've updated my example. After alot of wrestling, this regex almost works perfeclty: `(?:(?!{[a-zA-Z]{1,4}:[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b}))*{(?<key>[a-zA-Z]{1,4}):(?<name>[a-zA-Z]\w*\b)}(?!.*{[a-zA-Z]:\2)` The problem with this is that it doesn't match the first, but the last one found.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390779/how-to-use-j-modifier-in-php/28390881#28390881 Maybe `PREG_SET_ORDER` matters?

Answer (score 0):

You can make workaround. Set proxy names (multi-group without duplicates) and get what you want in code.

If you want regexp:

```
{s:varName}-{i:varName}-{s:varName}
```

write out:

```
{s:varName-1}-{i:varName-2}-{s:varName-3}
```

And write some logic:

- get all groups for `varName-*` (`varName-1`, `varName-2`, `varName-3`),
- get what you want (for example fist occurrence it is `varName-1`).

For this regexp:

```
{i:varName1}-{d:varName1}-{i:varName2}-{i:varName3}-{m:varName3}
```

write:

```
{i:varName1-1}-{d:varName1-2}-{i:varName2-1}-{i:varName3-1}-{m:varName3-2}
```

And the same logic:

- get all groups for `varName1-*` (`varName1-1`, `varName1-2`), for `varName2-*`, `varName3-*`, etc.
- get `*-1` from all multi-groups (`varName1-1`, `varName2-1`, `varName3-1`)

I use this workaround, because some other languages (for example Java) doesn't support duplicate group names.